# Convert md5 hash code of javascript to Python return different result

Tags: javascript, python, base64, md5

Currently, I have the following `Javascript` code that required to be converted to Python code

```
var requestContent = CryptoJS.MD5('{ "agentSessionId": "1622024176" }');
var requestContentBase64String = requestContent.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

this return the following result `bwtSmXFDxoG4cb0HDrZbhQ==`

On the other hand, I wrote the following `Python` code:

```
request_content = hashlib.md5('{ "agentSessionId": "1622024176" }').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
request_content_base64_string = base64.b64encode(request_content.encode())
```

but it returned a different result `NmYwYjUyOTk3MTQzYzY4MWI4NzFiZDA3MGViNjViODU=`

Can someone tell me why these 2 return different results when both do 2 jobs of `md5 hashing` and `encode to base64 string`
and how do I go about changing the Python code for it to work?

Comment: the first base64 string encodes the binary value of the hash, the second one the hexadecimal representation of the hash.

Comment: I wouldn't count on `str({ "agentSessionId": "1622024176" })` being the same value as `'{ "agentSessionId": "1622024176" }'`… In fact, it won't be.

Comment: @deceze i updated the question with the string version, still not close to the expected result of javascript side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (I changed hexdigest to digest):

```
import hashlib, base64
# JAVA version: bwtSmXFDxoG4cb0HDrZbhQ==
request_content = hashlib.md5('{ "agentSessionId": "1622024176" }'.encode('utf-8')).digest()
request_content_base64_string = base64.b64encode(request_content)
print(request_content_base64_string)
```

Result:

```
b'bwtSmXFDxoG4cb0HDrZbhQ=='
```

Answer (score 0):

> change ur python code to this :

```
import hashlib
import base64

magic = '{ "agentSessionId": "1622024176" }'
magic = hashlib.md5(magic.encode())
magic = magic.digest()
magic1= base64.b64encode(magic)
encodedStr = str(magic1, "utf-8")
print(encodedStr)
```